# Compile Kotlin with a jar dependency from a command line

Tags: command-line, compilation, kotlin

I have a project with a mixture of Java and Kotlin files. Until recently I've been succesfully compiling it from the command line using a simple script like this:

```
export CLASSPATH=java/main

# compile Kotlin files
find java/main/ -type d \
| xargs kotlinc-jvm -cp java/lib/google-collections-0.9.jar -d java/main/

# compile Java files
find java/main/ -name '*.java' | xargs javac
```

Then I started using the JGraphT library, so that created a dependancy on the jgrapht jar. The library is referenced from the Kotlin files. I can still compile my project from IntelliJ, but can't get the command-line script working.

Here's what I have tried:

1. Add the jar to CLASSPATH. Doesn't work. Kotlin compiler doesn't see it. It probably ignores the CLASSPATH.
2. Add the jar as another `-cp` parameter:

   `find java/main/ -type d \
   | xargs kotlinc-jvm \
       -cp java/lib/google-collections-0.9.jar \
           java/lib/jgrapht-core-0.9.1.jar \
       -d java/main/`

Then I get the following error:

```
error: source entry is not a Kotlin file: java/lib/jgrapht-core-0.9.1.jar
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is a small hobby project, mainly to play around with Kotlin. That's why I'm not using any build system, such as Ant or Gradle. (Another reason is I don't have any experience with these and they look scary. :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it happens, I managed to find the problem myself immediately after posting the question. The arguments to the `-cp` parameter have to be separated by a colon (:), not a space. The following works just fine:

```
find java/main/ -type d \
| xargs kotlinc-jvm \
    -cp java/lib/google-collections-0.9.jar:java/lib/jgrapht-core-0.9.1.jar \
    -d java/main/
```

Comment: correct, it uses the current operating system path separator.

Comment: I'm facing the same but your solution does not seem to work, maybe I misunderstood...

I have tried this, before seeing your post
kotlinc-jvm ".\src\main.kt" ".\src\myLib.kt" -cp .\bin\selenium\client-combined-3.141.59.jar .\bin\gson-2.8.8.jar -include-runtime -d ".\myApp.jar"
and the issue was the same -> 2nd .jar file (gson here) is ignored and compiler outputs "source entry is not a Kotlin file"

Changing to
kotlinc-jvm ".\src\main.kt" ".\src\myLib.kt" -cp .\bin\selenium\client-combined-3.141.59.jar:.\bin\gson-2.8.8.jar -include-runtime -d ".\myApp.jar"
also the 1st is ignored

Comment: In Windows: from documentation it seems the ":" has to be change to ";". So, I tried:  
kotlinc-jvm ".\src\main.kt" ".\src\myLib.kt" -cp ".\bin\selenium\client-combined-3.141.59.jar;.\bin\gson-2.8.8.jar" -include-runtime -d ".\myApp.jar"    but exception is like the first attempt's one: "error: source entry is not a Kotlin file: .\bin\gson-2.8.8.jar"

Comment: I tried the same in Linux but with ":" instead of ";" as separator, as you did. It works well...so how can I write it in windows terminal? Should I post a new questtion?